# Passing 'None' as function parameter (where parameter is a function)

Tags: python, lambda

I am writing a small app that has to perform some 'sanity checks' before entering execution. (eg. of a sanity check: test if a certain path is readable / writable / exists)

The code:

```
import logging
import os
import shutil
import sys
from paths import PATH

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
log = logging.getLogger('sf.core.sanity')

def sanity_access(path, mode):
    ret = os.access(path, mode)
    logfunc = log.debug if ret else log.warning
    loginfo = (os.access.__name__, path, mode, ret)
    logfunc('%s(\'%s\', %s)==%s' % loginfo)
    return ret

def sanity_check(bool_func, true_func, false_func):
    ret = bool_func()
    (logfunc, execfunc) = (log.debug, true_func) if ret else \
        (log.warning, false_func)
    logfunc('exec: %s', execfunc.__name__)
    execfunc()

def sanity_checks():
    sanity_check(lambda: sanity_access(PATH['userhome'], os.F_OK), \
                 lambda: None, sys.exit)
```

My question is related to the `sanity_check` function.

This function takes 3 parameters (`bool_func`, `true_func`, `false_func`). If the `bool_func` (which is the test function, returning a boolean value) fails, `true_func` gets executed, else the `false_func` gets executed.

**1)** `lambda: None` is a little lame , because for example if the sanity_access returns True, `lambda: None` gets executed, and the output printed will be:

```
DEBUG:sf.core.sanity:access('/home/nomemory', 0)==True
DEBUG:sf.core.sanity:exec: <lambda>
```

So it won't be very clear in the logs what function got executed. The log will only contain `<lambda>` . Is there a default function that does nothing and can be passed as a parameter ? Is it a way to return the name of the first function that is being executed inside a lambda ?

Or a way not to log that "exec" if 'nothing' is sent as a paramter ?

What's the none / do-nothing equivalent for functions ?

```
sanity_check(lambda: sanity_access(PATH['userhome'], os.F_OK), \
                 <do nothing, but show something more useful than <lambda>>, sys.exit)
```

Additional question, why is `lambda: pass` instead of `lambda: None` not working ?

Comment: Wow that's complex.  Why so complex?

Comment: Exercising the 'lambda thing', plus i'll have to perform a lot of checks.

Comment: The "lambda thing" isn't helping, is it?  A lot of checks doesn't justify his complexity.  Why not just use `if` statements?

Comment: No, not helping, but nice to have & now.

Comment: You could just try to write to the path and log if that fails.

Comment: @Andrei You are trying to write lisp in python.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth  Some people claim that you can do a lot of things the functional-way in python... I tried my luck, and come with a "complicated" / less readable solution. @THC4k solution is way better for example.

Comment: @Andrei, Python is largely an imperative language with some support for functional programming. It does have first class objects so that higher order functions are possible (this and macros are where lisp really gets its power). But don't get distracted with lambdas - they're seldom useful in python. The real power of python comes from decorators and metaclasses. And it's still not lisp.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth I will try to document more on : decorators and metaclasses. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Functional programming does **not** mean to write lots of functions or to pass functions around! It means to write simple, obviously correct and reuseable functions and then use them to put together more complex functions. FP works very well in Python, but its less about passing functions around and more about using LCs, generators and itertools.

Comment: @Andrei Ciobanu: "No, not helping,"  Agreed.  "but nice to have & [know]".  Not really.  Since it doesn't help, it isn't nice to know.  Indeed, this overly complex thing is neither nice to have nor nice to know.  It's not a good idea.

Comment: @AndreiCiobanu I guess I'll be the sole dissenting commenter by actually liking your approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's with all the lambdas that serve no purpose? Well, maybe optional arguments will help you a bit:

```
def sanity_check( test, name='undefined', ontrue=None, onfalse=None ):
    if test:
        log.debug(name)
        if ontrue is not None:
            ontrue()
    else:
        log.warn( name )
        if onfalse is not None:
            onfalse()

def sanity_checks():
    sanity_check(sanity_access(PATH['userhome'], os.F_OK), 'test home', 
        onfalse=sys.exit)
```

But you are *really* overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 8):

### update

I would normally delete this post because THC4k saw through all the complexity and rewrote your function correctly. However in a different context, the K combinator trick might come in handy, so I'll leave it up.

---

There is no builtin that does what you want AFIK. I believe that you want the [K combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) (the link came up on another question) which can be encoded as

```
 def K_combinator(x, name):
     def f():
         return x
     f.__name__ = name
     return f

 none_function = K_combinator(None, 'none_function')

 print none_function()
```

of course if this is just a one off then you could just do

```
def none_function():
    return None
```

But then you don't get to say "K combinator". Another advantage of the 'K_combinator' approach is that you can pass it to functions, for example,

```
foo(call_back1, K_combinator(None, 'name_for_logging'))
```

as for your second statement, only expressions are allowed in `lambda`. `pass` is a statement. Hence, `lambda: pass` fails.

You can slightly simplify your call to sanity check by removing the lambda around the first argument.

```
def sanity_check(b, true_func, false_func):
    if b:
        logfunc = log.debug
        execfunc = true_func
    else:
        logfunc = log.warning
        execfunc = false_func
    logfunc('exec: %s', execfunc.__name__)
    execfunc()

def sanity_checks():
    sanity_check(sanity_access(PATH['userhome'], os.F_OK),
                 K_combinator(None, 'none_func'), sys.exit)
```

This is more readable (largely from expanding the ternary operator into an if). the `boolfunc` wasn't doing anything because `sanity_check` wasn't adding any arguments to the call. Might as well just call instead of wrapping it in a lambda.

Comment: I got to say "K Combinator" a few times, then I followed the SKI link down a rabbit hole of combinatory logic, lambda calculus, unlambda and applicative programming languages and then I completely forgot what I was looking for on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to rethink this.

```
class SanityCheck( object ):
    def __call__( self ):
        if self.check():
            logger.debug(...)
            self.ok()
        else:
            logger.warning(...)
            self.not_ok()
    def check( self ):
        return True
    def ok( self ):
        pass
    def not_ok( self ):
        sys.exit(1)

class PathSanityCheck(SanityCheck):
    path = "/path/to/resource"
    def check( self ):
        return os.access( path, os.F_OK )

class AnotherPathSanityCheck(SanityCheck):
    path = "/another/path"

def startup():
    checks = ( PathSanityCheck(), AnotherPathSanityCheck() )
    for c in checks:
        c()
```

Callable objects can simplify your life.

Comment: I think you want to be extending `SanityCheck` instead of objects ;)

Comment: @S.Lott : Your example is a good (readable) alternative. But one thing: isn't one subclass of SanityCheck enough, that receives path / mode as parameter ? Another thing: What if sometimes when not_ok() i want to perform a completely different tasks instead of sys.exit() . Same for ok()...

Comment: @Andrei Ciobanu: You can always override `ok` and `not_ok` in a subclass.

Comment: @mipadi That could be a solution. An OOP one.

Comment: This is actually more complicated than what OP posted after you strip out all of the logging info. Or at least from my perspective.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: That's a hard case to make.  This uses simple inheritance and no "apply a random function-like thing to random arguments" mechanisms.  Just simple inheritance and ordinary procedural programming.  It takes up more lines of code for a reason -- to make the processing painfully obvious.  Not subtle.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import dis
>>> f = lambda: None
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE    

>>> g = lambda: Pass 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> dis.dis(g)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Pass)
              3 RETURN_VALUE 


>>> g = lambda: pass 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    g = lambda: pass 
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: AaronMcSmooth has already explained why it wouldn't work. I thought not to replicate it and write it again in my reply.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you want is a function which does nothing, but has a `__name__` which is useful to the log. The lambda function is *doing* exactly what you want, but `execfunc.__name__` is giving `"<lambda>"`. Try one of these:

```
def nothing_func():
    return
def ThisAppearsInTheLog():
    return
```

You can also put your own attributes on functions:

```
def log_nothing():
       return
log_nothing.log_info = "nothing interesting"
```

Then change `execfunc.__name__` to   `getattr(execfunc,'log_info', '')`